# Как правильно развернуть приложение react-native в Visual Studio Emulator for Android?

Tags: visual-studio, mobile-development, react-native, hyper-v, android-emulator

Подскажите пож-та, как правильно развернуть приложение в эмуляторе?

Моё окружение:
Windows 10 pro
Приложение react-native, сгенерированное через create-react-native-app
Visual Studio Emulator for Android
Expo XDE

Пробовал запускать через Expo XDE (Device -> Open on Android) - получаю ошибку: 
No Android device found. Please connect a device and follow the instructions here to enable USB debugging:
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html#developer-device-options. If you are using Genymotion go to Settings -> ADB, select "Use custom Android SDK tools", and point it at your Android SDK directory.

Через cli тоже проблема, судя по всему для запуска через cli нужен Andriod Studio, а я хотел бы обойтись просто своей любимой IDE'шкой и эмулятором Visual Studio.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы порекомендовал попробовать так:

- поставить Android Studio(нам от неё нужны только эмуляторы)
- создать эмулятор требуемого девайса. *Проверить список доступных эмуляторов можно `emulator -list-avds`*
- запустить эмулятор из CLI: `Android/emulator/emulator ИМЯ_ЭМУЛЯТОРА`
- убедиться что эмулятор виден через `adb devices`
- задеплоить на него свое приложение из Expo XDE (Device -> Open on Android)

Получится вот так:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А дальше можно продолжать править код проекта в любимом редакторе.